# Instantiate and return an object in one line

Tags: c#

The code below, which works, shows the returning of an object when the object is instantiated. Why does this work? In my mind, I can understand a "Return new ...", or instantiate Dummy1 on a separate line and "Return Dummy1".

```
    public class TestClass1
    {
        public string s = "test2";
    }

    public TestClass1 GetTestClass()
    {
        TestClass1 dummy1;
        return dummy1 = new TestClass1();         //  Why is this valid?
    }
```

Comment: Note in C#, the convention is to use PascalCase for type names and camelCase for variable names. It helps to follow these conventions: it will make your code more readable for others and increase the likelihood that you'll receive help.

Comment: [_"The assignment operator = assigns the value of its right-hand operand to a variable, a property, or an indexer element given by its left-hand operand. **The result of an assignment expression is the value assigned to the left-hand operand**."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator). You might consider getting in the habit of consulting the documentation for features rather than posting questions that are easily answered by consulting the documentation for features.

Comment: Thank you Peter, In an ideal world, yes, consulting documentation for features sounds like a great idea. In practice, it's not realistic. Time is never on our side, which is why Stackoverflow is a vital tool for me and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in C#, an assignment is also an expression that yields a value.

Try this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str1 = "foo";
        var str2 = (str1 = "bar");
        Console.WriteLine(str2);
    }
}
```

You'll see that `str2` will hold the value of `str1` which is being assigned the value `"bar"`.